# Can you "group" shapes in SVG so each is filled only once - even if they overlap?

Tags: svg, colors, fill

In the example code shown below is there any way in SVG to have the fill only applied once to the whole shape/group?

Currently each individual shape is filled separately - so because the circles overlap the rect and the fill color is semi-opaque  you get darker bits where the circles overlap the rect.

I tried using the fill-rule attribute set to evenodd but it didn't appear to have any effect.

```html
 <html>
    <body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
        <g fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
            <rect x="50" y="30" height="40" width="75" />
            <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
        </g>
    </svg>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please try this path instead of the shapes in the group: `<path d="M50,30h75a20,20 0 0 1 0 40h-75a20,20 0 0 1 0 -40z"/>`

Comment: I take it the "fill-rule" attribute is not for this purpose?

Comment: Alternatively you can use solid colors. For this you can use a rgba to rgb convertor like this one: https://borderleft.com/toolbox/rgba/. In your example rgba(255,0,0,0.5) on a white background can be replaced with rgb(255,128,128)

Comment: fill-rule is used when you have a path or a polygon to determine the insideness of a point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule

Comment: I was worried that that was going to be said. It's not really a rect - that was just an example. The real shape is a bendy rectangle like this: https://www.rgraph.net/images/svg-activity-meter-snippet.png Still doable I guess, just a fair bit more code. Cheers.

Comment: If you're interested - I drew the shape again on top of what's already there. the shape below has whatever color the user specifies and the highlight shape on top is rgba(255,255,255,0.5) so it lightens whatever the color is. There's an image here: https://www.rgraph.net/images/svg-activity-meter-snippet2.png The top bar is highlighted - the unhighlighted color is red so the semi-opaque highlight shape on top of it brightens it.

Comment: just an idea: instead of a filled shape I would use stroke with `stroke-linecap: round` and a thick stroke-width

Comment: That's another way I guess - but it's done now and I ain't redoing it! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use solid colors, but make the `<g>` semi-opaque:

```
<g fill="rgba(255,0,0)" opacity=".5">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qwydhvx0/

Comment: This might have saved me some time. :-/

Comment: I just got around to trying this - and it works a treat. Cheers!